# traverse all the disks or get hd_struct by device name in kernel module

Tags: drivers, kernel, disk

I'm writing a kernel module(on linux 2.6.32), to get the `disk_stats` of all the disks(not partition) in use. In other words, I'm getting the data just like what `/sys/block/sda/stat` shows, but in kernel module.

(NOTE: By 'not partition', I mean we just handle `sda` and ignore `sda1/sda2/etc`, for example.)

Is there anything like `for_each_netdev` or `for_each_possible_cpu` for block device? Beacuse there may be multiple disks and I need a way to traverse them. Or at the latest, how can I get the related data structure with the block device's name(like `sda`)?

I know we can get a disk's `disk_stats` from the disk's `hd_struct`, but how could I get this `hd_struct`?

I have read linux2.6.32/block/genhd.c, and I know the content of file `/sys/block/sda/stat` is generated by `diskstats_show`. But how does the second argument come?

Please help me. thanks.